# PIC CAN test code not working as expected

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, can-bus

I had created a simple test code for CAN using PIC18F4580. Which consists of 2 nodes sending data between each other. Uses 11-bit standard ID for communication. Node-1 is given ID of 10 and Node-2 is given ID of 20. I tried to display the registers like `COMSTAT`, `TXB0CON`, `RXB0CON` on the LCD here are the register contents.

```
COMSTAT = 0x00
TXB0CON = 0x00
RXB0CON = 0x01
```

- When key is pressed it will first show the contents of COMSTAT, TXB0CON and RXB0CON on LCD in sequence.
- Then at the end it will put the message frame ID = XX, Data = NDx on CAN Bus
- Node-1 puts ND2 on data field D0(N), D1(D) and D2(2) with DLC is 3 and ID = 20.
- Similarly Node-2 puts ND1 on data field D0(N), D1(D) and D2(1) with DLC is 3 and ID = 10 (Please refer the **Test code** given).

Both the nodes send the data but Node-1 is only receiving. And showing ID = 00 instead of 10, and received data is displayed as some garbage on LCD.

[Test code link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xn81n_IjszizNUvd4E5bN0jpFeC2oGLI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please post the relevant code here on this site, in the form of a [mcve].